# C# library to Copy New and Modified directories/files

Tags: c#, .net, backup, datemodified

I want to build an application that will copy all new and modified files from a source folder path to a destination backup path.  I know I can use a brute force loop through all files in source directory and compare in destination directory (see code below).  I was just wondering if there is a script out that that will accompplish this.  I am more concerned with modified files then new files.

```
// all files
Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


// last file modified time
FileSystemInfo.LastWriteTime(filepath)
```

Comment: I agree with @elgonzo, a "script" will do the same thing you would anyway.  The only way I can think of doing it so that "brute force" method isn't visible to you is to use robocopy /mir :)

Comment: `I am more concerned with modified files then new files`, then use [FilesystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks L.B.  FilesystemWatcher is exactly what I am looking for.